normalizing weights efficiently in python
I want to normalize weights within subgroups in a list/array. I have a working version now but it looks cumbersome and i feel there is a much more efficient way to do this. Btw, I have experience with Matlab and trying to get things going with Python.
Original weights
w = np.array([9,20,5,3,8,5,8,10,4,3,3,2,5,5,2,3,2,1,2])/100

Within w, there are 5 different subgroups [0:5], [6:12], [12:14], [14:16], [16:18]
For each of the subgroups I would like to normalize the weights. What I do now for each subgroup is
grp_1 = w[0:5]/sum(w[0:5])
grp_2 = w[6:12]/sum(w[6:12])
grp_3 = w[12:14]/sum(w[12:14])
grp_4 = w[14:16]/sum(w[14:16])
grp_5 = w[16:18]/sum(w[16:18])

And then I need to concatenate into one vector/list
w_norm = np.concatenate([grp_1, grp_2, grp_3, grp_4, grp_5])

I feel like comprehensions would do but I can't get it to work. Mind that the original weight vector will change (as well as subgroup definitions), and I will have to change the partitions manually, which is error prone.
Any suggestions? Or maybe just point to a resource or what do i need to google?
Thanks in advance, J

Not an answer to the question but I am curious as to why between grp_1 and grp_2 you are missing the 5 in the fifth position. Should grp_1 be [0:6] or perhaps grp_2 be [5:12]?

And last element w[18] also...

That was part of my question, I could use all of the elements or leave one or more out of the process.

If there are some values left out in the middle, Andrew's comment on my solution is probably your best bet.

If missed values are an errors, then:
import numpy as np

w = np.array([9,20,5,3,8,5,8,10,4,3,3,2,5,5,2,3,2,1,2])/100

group = [0, 5, 12, 14, 16, len(w)]

w_norm = np.concatenate([w[i:j]/np.sum(w[i:j]) for i, j in zip(group[:-1], group[1:])])


import numpy as np

w = np.array([9,20,5,3,8,5,8,10,4,3,3,2,5,5,2,3,2,1,2])/100

# is this supposed to be 0:5, 5:12? or 0:6, 6:12?
groups = [(0, 5), (6, 12), (12, 14), (14, 16), (16, 18)]

w_norm = np.concatenate( [w[group[0]:group[1]]/sum(w[group[0]:group[1]]) for group in groups])
print(w_norm)

The code is a bit of a mess, but list comprehensions usually are!
w[group[0]:group[1]]/sum(w[group[0]:group[1]]) is the same as your 5 group statements, just generalized so we can have a list of tuples called groups with the start and end values.
On the side of human error, depending on how the subgroups are determined, you could auto-generate groups rather than manually typing it out.

Slighty better version is
w_norm = np.concatenate([w[i:j]/sum(w[j:j]) for i, j in groups])
